# How to specify a theme in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I designed a tool using the 'qt4-designer' and developed the code for it on a lubuntu 64 bit VM. Everything worked fine on my VM and other lubuntu machines. Although when i tried running it on an ubuntu vm. The UI seemed completely different. It seemed boxy, kind of like windows 95 UI's. I couldn't find an option to specify a theme in the designer either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Qt using the default OS design, so the applications looks different on differents OS. I think you can not change it by easy way.

Answer (score 1):

If the target platform has no defined style for Qt4 (or it defines a non-existent style), Qt will default to using the Windows style.

Users on the target system can set the style for all Qt4 applications by using the [qtconfig tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconfig.html). This may not be installed by default, though (it probably lives in separate package in many Linux distros).